# Changing TextInput font color

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, textinput

I have a TextInput field and I was able to change its background and placeholder color fine, but the input text does not change here is what I have

```
<TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            backgroundColor="#533AED"
            placeholder="What may we call you?"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            value={name}
            onChangeText={name => setName(name)}
            selectionColor="white"
          />
```

And this is my style

```
input: {
    height: 55,
    width: '80%',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 3,
    color: 'white',
  },
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried other changes but nothing seems to work

Comment: To change the color of the input text all you have to change is the `color` in your style. You don't need `selectionColor` prop.

Comment: The ```selectionColor```is for the typing bar, and when I change the color it doesn't change the font color.

Comment: it works see here https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmed_gaber/textinput